# Looping animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i loop animate function using jquery? i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".b").click(function(){
                    var a=$(".abb");
                    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'400px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'20px',left:'500px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'500px',left:'100px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'800px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'200px',left:'100px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'300px',left:'0px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'600px',left:'300px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'700px'},"slow");
                    a.animate({top:'300px',left:'100px'},"slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="b"> click </button>
        <div class="abb" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#9F0;position:absolute;border-radius:70px;box-shadow:#000 1px 1px 3px 2px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want the above script to work continuously. please assist

Comment: You can use a `setTimeout()` inside of its `complete()` that called it back again.

Comment: can u pls show me the example

Comment: Refer to my answer.  Enjoy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this. this will animate start again after every 5 seconds you can increase it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b").click(function(){
    setInterval(animate_me,5000);
});
});

function animate_me()
{
  var a=$(".abb");
    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'400px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'20px',left:'500px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'500px',left:'100px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'800px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'200px',left:'100px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'300px',left:'0px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'600px',left:'300px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'700px'},"slow");
    a.animate({top:'300px',left:'100px'},"slow");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [I like mine better.](http://jsfiddle.net/85bLx/)

### jQuery/JS

```
var a=$(".abb");
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b").click(moveIt);
});
function moveIt(){
    a.animate({top:'100px',left:'400px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'20px',left:'500px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'500px',left:'100px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'100px',left:'800px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'200px',left:'100px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'300px',left:'0px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'600px',left:'300px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'100px',left:'700px'},"slow")
    .animate({top:'300px',left:'100px'},"slow");
    setTimeout(moveIt, 6000);
}
```

Comment: use `SetInterval` . the `setInterval` code executes every 6000ms exactly, while the setTimeout waits 6000ms, runs the function, which takes some ms, then sets another timeout. So the wait period is actually greater than 6000ms.

Comment: That reasoning actually proves why `setInterval()` is not good to use here.  If you call the function at that "6000ms exactly" as you say, it will continue to queue and could interfere with other code.  Calling itself with `setTimeout` ensures that each execution isn't waiting for the last one to finish before firing.

Answer (score 0):

you can Move and stop as well by using a flag `move` true/false like this AS i used the answer of **Deryck**

**HTML**

```
<button class="b">Move</button><button class="s">Stop</button>
<div class="abb" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#9F0;position:absolute;border-radius:70px;box-shadow:#000 1px 1px 3px 2px;"></div>
```

**jquery**

```
var move;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b").click(function(){
          move = true;
          setInterval(animate_me,6000);

    });

     $(".s").click(function(){
          move = false;

    });

});
function animate_me()
{
    if(move===true)
    {    
       var a=$(".abb");
       a.animate({top:'100px',left:'400px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'20px',left:'500px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'500px',left:'100px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'100px',left:'800px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'200px',left:'100px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'300px',left:'0px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'600px',left:'300px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'100px',left:'700px'},"slow");
       a.animate({top:'300px',left:'100px'},"slow");
    }     
}
```

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X8f9j/)